# I keep getting [object][Object] as my request from a form with a POST request method while using node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have been trying to get the value of my text input in a form with a POST request, but on the server side, the `req.body` is returning a `[objecet][Object]` request, when indeed I put in a value. Here's my code

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
let app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//Middleware for 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))

//using a middleware to map the /assets link in the url
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

//Setting the view engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

//Contact page
app.get('/contact', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html');
  // res.sendFile(__dirname + '/assets/appUI.js'); 
})
app.get('/contact-us', (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/contact.html'); 
})

//Handling  POST request
app.post('/', (req, res )=>{
  console.log('The task is '+ req.body)
})

app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('The server is up and listening at port 3000!!!')
})
```

My index.html code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" type="image/x-icon">
  <title>To do app</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
</script>
</head>
<body onload ="appui()">
  <p><a href="contact">CONTACT US</a></p>
  <img src="todoImage.png" alt="" class="todoImage">
  <div class="main-box">
    <div class = "form-error animated shake" id = "error-message">
        <p class = "form-error"><small>Please add a task</small></p> 
    </div>
    <div class = "form-registered animated shake" id = "registered-message">
        <p class = "form-registered"><small>Details added to register!</small></p> 
    </div>
    <h1>Todo App </h1><br>
    <form class="form" action="/" method="POST">
          <input type="text"  id="task" name = "task" value="Invents"><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Add task" class="btn" name="addTask">
          <input type="button" value="Clear All" class="btn clear-all"  name="clearTask">
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul class="task-list"></ul>
  <script src= "appUI.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And my client side javascript code is as below

```
function appui(){
//Grabing input
const task = document.querySelector('#task');
const submit = document.querySelector('.btn');
const main = document.querySelector('.main-box');
const form =  document.querySelector('.form');
const taskList = document.querySelector('.task-list');
const clearTask = document.querySelector('.clear-all')
const errorMessage = document.querySelector('#error-message');
const registeredMessage = document.querySelector('#registered-message');
//Load event listener
// loadEventlisntener()
console.log(main)
//adding submit event
submit.addEventListener('click', addTask);

//Funtion Error Display
function errorDisplay(){
  errorMessage.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
}
//Funtion regsitered Display
function registeredDisplay(){
  registeredMessage.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
}

//addtask
//Function addTask
function addTask(e){
  if(task.value !== '') {

    //create Element li
    let list = document.createElement('li');
    //Add a class name
    list.className = 'task-value';

    //create div
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    //Add a class name
    div.className = 'main-box task animated heartBeat';

    //task
    let taskInput = document.createTextNode(`${task.value}`);

    //append text node
    div.appendChild(taskInput);
    //Anchor tag
    let anch = document.createElement('a');
    //Add a class name
    anch.className = 'deleteIcon';

    //Delete mark 'X'
    anch.innerHTML = `<b class="delete-icon">Delete</b>`
    //Append Anchor tag to div
    div.appendChild(anch);

    // main.appendChild(div);
    // form.parentNode.insertBefore(div, form.nextSibling);
    console.log(div)

    // Inserting Element after
    // main.parentNode.insertBefore(div, main.nextSibling);
    document.querySelector('.task-list').appendChild(div); 


    registeredMessage.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
    setTimeout(registeredDisplay, 3000);
    task.value ='';

    } else{
      errorMessage.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
      setTimeout(errorDisplay, 3000);  
  }
// e.preventDefault();
}

  //Deleting task
  taskList.addEventListener('click', removeTask);

  // Remove Task
  function removeTask(e) {
  if(e.target.parentElement.classList.contains('deleteIcon')) {
  e.target.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
  }
}

//Clear all tasks
clearTask.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  if(taskList.innerHTML === ''){
    errorMessage.style.setProperty('display', 'block');
      setTimeout(errorDisplay, 3000);  
  }else if(confirm('Are you sure ?')){
    taskList.innerHTML = '';
    task.value ='';
  }
})
}
```

I'm already so frustrated, I hope you all can help out.
Thanks!

Comment: `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Just `+` (concatenating) an object onto a string [will give you `"[object Object]"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Description). You can get a useful representation by passing it as a separate argument – `console.log('The task is ', req.body)`. Or, you'll need to specify the format – `console.log('The task is ' + JSON.stringify(req.body))`.

Comment: Yes. Thanks works great! But now the form values are coming out as empty strings `[' ' ]` when indeed I put values in the form. Not sure if it is my frontend code causing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The automatic string conversion in Javascript for an object is just `[Object][object]` so when you do this:

```
console.log('The task is '+ req.body)
```

that's what is happening.  `req.body` undergoes an automatic string conversion to `[Object][object]` and that's appended to your string.

To fix, change your code to this:

```
console.log('The task is ', req.body);
```

so that `console.log()` can output the whole `req.body` object.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well! But then another problem comes in, when I do `req.body.task`, it returns an empty value when indeed I put a value in the form, I suspecting this is caused by the frontend codes, I checked over and over, but couldn't figure it out. I await a helpful response once again.thanks!

Comment: @fisayo.obilaja - What does `console.log(req.body)` show?

Comment: `console.log(req.body)` shows `[task : '', Add task:'Add Task', Clear all :'clear-all']` that's what I get.

Comment: @fisayo.obilaja - Seems like your `task` field is empty in the form when you submit it.

Comment: That's what it's saying, but I actually put in some value. If you look closely at my HTML code, you'd see I event put a value of `value = "invent" ` in the text input. But, it still logs an empty value. To deviate a little, before I even got to load my front end script `appUI.js`, I had to put an `onload` event on the body tag in order to let the JavaScript load, I don't know if all these errors are from the front end script. I have the project on github should in case you want to run it.

Comment: I don't understand your front end JS (seems very confusing to me). But, I do see this: `task.value ='';`.  It appears like you're putting tasks into text nodes and then clearing the form field values.

Comment: problem solved! I will check another way to clear the task input after a task I added. Thank you so much for making get the problem of this errors! I hope this helps others too!